# how can i update Gridview automatically when a record inserted of updated in asp.net without refresh page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, jquery, gridview

i have a gridview that dispaly some comments and i want to update or refresh it with new comments and new  data that inserted or modified in database for all online client.example facebook or google+.
i programming with c# and visual studio 2012 and Sqlserver 2012.

Comment: To start you looking in the write direction check out the `UpdatePanel` control

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to set the page to auto refresh every few minutes. This can be done with a specific meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

The above example will refresh the page every five minutes.

Another approach is to put the GridView inside an UpdatePanel with a Timer that will periodically refresh the GridView.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Both approaches will stress your web server, so choose the refresh interval carefully.

Finally, if you are in ASP.NET 4.5 you can use SSE (Server Sent Events) to update each page when only a change occurs. Checkout [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), a transparent implementation of SSE in ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks 
but i use these wayes but i want to when a record inserted i display a popup or other way to show that comment to online client not refresh priodicaly.i want to some thing for example a trigger to tell asp.net that a recored has been inserted.and add it to Gridview

Comment: I see. So you are asking how to inform the user that the GridView is changed? or a how to detect if changes have been made in the db?

Comment: thanks  codingstill ,yes i want to ask two question : how to detect if changes have been made in the db? and when i know change have been made in db, how can update data in Gridveiw for all online client?